# Windows 2000 under Windows 7 Virtual PC not working correctly

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have just moved my Windows 2000 Virtual PCs from Vista to Windows 7 Professional (64-bit). The machines work to a point but I have found some problems:

- drive mapping does not seem to work any more. I need this to exchange data. I do not need network access to the virtual PC so would rather leave it unconnected.
- the virtual PC would automatically shutdown the session and go to the login screen after a few minutes of inactivity.

I tried installing the Virtual PC Integration Components but the install failed (one of the messages basically says it's XP+ only). Now I'm stuck in 640x480 mode with mouse capture.

I have heard that you can install an older version of the Integration Components but this sounds a bit suspect.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get Windows2000 working with drive sharing on a Virtual PC?

Answer (score 1):

The additions / integration components from Virtual PC 2004 work.

[Download Virtual PC 2004 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3243)

Extract the contents of ZIP file. Then extract the contents of the MSI file with (will say install but it's just extracting):

```
msiexec /a "Microsoft Virtual PC 2004 MSDN.msi"
```

Where you installed/placed it look in XXX\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC\Virtual Machine Additions for VMAdditions.iso. Mount and use that to install additions into Windows 2000.

Comment: One problem: Sharing drives does not work and you can't drag and drop files. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The directory in Windows7 is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Virtual PC\Integration Components\"

But the ISO is protected or something. So I used WinISO 5.3 (freeware) to edit it, in its subfolder "\Windows", I added the 2004 VPC integration file mentioned above. Then (Very important) saved it as a new file called IntegrationCompNew.iso.

Afterward in the Settings of the Win2000 virtualpc file, I went to Optical drive and changed it from E: to point to an iso and this iso file is IntegrationCompNew.

I looked for it inside the booted Win2000 VPC. Went to the drive and Windows folder therein but after installation, the Inegration Feature is still greyed out. So I cannot direct the VPC to a use a local folder on my Windows 7 real laptop.

Comment: In the face of failure, I used HFS (simple file server) installed in my Win7 to move data across. Basically uploading from the Win2000 VPC to my Windows 7 RealPC.